# How to order records within a group_by

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a list of messages received. They are grouped by the 'from' field and ordered by created_at.

They are displayed like so in the businesses show view:

```
From: Tom
10pm Message7
8pm Message4
6pm Message2

From: Sara
9pm Message6
7pm Message3
5pm Message1

From: John
8pm Message5
```

In the businesses controller I have:

```
@messages = @business.short_messages.newest.group_by &:from
```

In the short_messages model I have the scope:

```
scope :newest, order: "created_at desc"
```

In the view I have:

```
<% @messages.each do |from, message| %>
 <p><%= from %></p>
 <% message.each do |msg| %>
  <p><%= msg.created_at %> <%= msg.content %></p>
 <% end %>
<% end %>
```

The grouping and ordering of the conversations is ok.

The problem is that I want the conversation with the newest message first but within that conversation it should be displayed last

```
From: Tom
6pm Message2
8pm Message4
10pm Message7

From: Sara
5pm Message1
7pm Message3
9pm Message6

From: John
8pm Message5
```

Comment: Since you want it ascending, why not just `scope :newest, order: "created_at ASC"` ?

Comment: @KappaNossi I think the groups are supposed to be ordered `ASC` whereas the rows in the groups are supposed to be ordered `DESC` on the same field, otherwise I don't see where the problem should be.

Comment: Correct. I want the conversation with the newest message first but within that conversation it should be displayed last

Answer (score 0):

Since you want it Ascending,just change your scope to

```
scope :newest, order: "created_at asc"
```

This Would work!

Comment: I want the conversation with the newest message first but within that conversation it should be displayed last

Answer (score 0):

I believe you cannot do that in a single database request, so you will need to do it manually afterwards. Try this:

```
@messages = @business.short_messages.newest.group_by &:from
@messages.each_pair { |k,v| v.sort!{|a,b| a.created_at <=> b.created_at} }
```

This code loops through the hash as key/value pairs and sorts the values (your messages). The sorting is directly applied to the referenced value object (note the ! in `sort!`) in your hash.

Answer (score 0):

Use `reverse_each` in the view to loop through the array in reverse

```
<% @messages.each do |from, message| %>
 <p><%= from %></p>
 <% message.reverse_each do |msg| %>
  <p><%= msg.created_at %> <%= msg.content %></p>
 <% end %>
<% end %>
```